# how to alias `read -p` on linux bash and store the user input in variable

Tags: bash, export, alias

I need to set alias for this command below but am unable to.

```
read -p 'Enter namespc: ' rvar
```

setting alias as a shorcut:

```
export gvar="read -p 'Enter namespc: ' rvar"
```

Actual Result:

```
$gvar
-bash: read: `namespc:': not a valid identifier
```

Expected: should list below to user on prompt and then save its value in rvar.

```
$gvar
Enter namespc:
```

echo $rvar

```
testspace
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a function instead of a variable (or an alias).

```
gvar () {
    read -p 'Enter names-can: ' rvar
}
```

Comment: nice.. and where do i save this? in ~/.bash_profile file. or ~./bashrc?

Comment: am getting syntax error when i added this to ~./bashrc
```
gvar() {
  read -p 'Enter namespace: ' rvar
  kubectl get ns -o yaml|grep $rvar -B3
}
```

Comment: @AhmFM What's the exact error? Also, do you have line breaks (or semicolons) between the `read` and `kubectl` commands, and also before the final "`}`"? Also, you should put double-quotes around `$rvar` and (depending on the version of `grep` may need to put the option first, that is: `grep -B3 "$rvar"`.

Comment: kubectl start on new line inside function.

-bash: /home/dtlu/.bashrc: line 318: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: /home/dtlu/.bashrc: line 318: `gmlu() {'

Comment: @AhmFM That error seems to indicate that the function definition is in an inappropriate place or context in the file. Make sure it's effectively by itself -- not being treated as part of something else. Do *not* try to combine it with an alias definition or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Ah Just realised, i need to use Alias not export.

answer is

```
alias gvar="read -p 'Enter namespc: ' rvar"
```

then call 
gvar and echo $rvar to validate